# Video link from video element with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I inspect the `YouTube` page in `Google Chrome` and noticed that in the `player` div there is video element with this id : `player_VIDEOID`.

And i want to get the `src Attribute` from this video element. 
So i load UIWebView with this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bnVUHWCynig"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[web loadRequest:requestObj];
```

And in `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`

I  implement a function in javascript that extract this src link with:

```
[web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"
     "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
     "script.text = \"function myFunction() { "
     "var videoele = document.getElementById('player_bnVUHWCynig');"
     "var url = videoele.getAttribute('src');"
     "return url;"
     "}\";"
     "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];

NSString * t = [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction();"];
```

And `t` always equal to empty string.

I try to run this `JS` function in `Chrome` and url is the src link in the video element.

What i did wrong in this method??

Comment: What's with all the quotes `"` in the middle your string without any backslashes?

Comment: Does your code compile though?

Comment: yep.i check the javascript code in google chrome

Comment: Did you solved this?